# How to get the largest prime in a binary search tree?

Tags: c++, tree

I'm writing a program to print the largest prime in a binary search tree, this is my program:

```
bool isPrime(int number) {
    bool is_prime = true;

    if (number == 0 || number == 1)
        is_prime = false;

    for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            is_prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return is_prime;
}

BSTNode* largestPrime(BSTNode* root)
{
    BSTNode* temp = new BSTNode;
    temp->data = 0;

    if (root != nullptr) {
        largestPrime(root->left);
        if (isPrime(root->data) && temp->data < root->data)
            temp->data = root->data;
        largestPrime(root->right);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

But the output is always `0`, I don't know how to fix this, can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks for your help !

Comment: start with `isPrime` - what it should return for `2`?

Comment: When `largestPrime` is called, should the value returned be ignored, as you are doing?

Comment: @IłyaBursov As far as I can see `isPrime` will return `true` for `2`, which is correct.

Comment: my bad, missed default value

Comment: Why do you think calling `largestPrime(root->left);` would change `temp`? It makes it's own temp which you then throw away because you ignore the return value.

Answer (score 0):

First change `largestPrime` to return an `int`. Don't know why you made it return a pointer.

Second, don't ignore the return values of the recursive calls to `largestPrime`. That should have been a red flag.

Something like this

```
int largestPrime(BSTNode* root)
{
    int max = 0;
    if (root != nullptr) {
        int temp = largestPrime(root->left);
        if (isPrime(temp) && max < temp)
            max = temp;
        if (isPrime(root->data) && max < root->data)
            max = root->data;
        temp = largestPrime(root->right);
        if (isPrime(temp) && max < temp)
            max = temp;
    }
    return max;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a similar version that returns a pointer to the node containing the largest prime.

```
BSTNode* largestPrime(BSTNode* root)
{
    BSTNode* max = nullptr;
    if (root != nullptr) {
        BSTNode* temp = largestPrime(root->left);
        if (temp && isPrime(temp->data) && (max == nullptr || max->data < temp->data))
            max = temp;
        if (isPrime(root->data) && (max == nullptr || max < root->data))
            max = root->data;
        temp = largestPrime(root->right);
        if (temp && isPrime(temp->data) && (max == nullptr || max->data < temp->data))
            max = temp;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, the problem ask me to return a pointer.

Comment: OK I'll update with a pointer returning version.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with isPrime to make it a little bit faster and easier to read:

```
bool isPrime(int number) {
    if (number <= 1) return false; // negatives, 0 and 1 are not primes
    if (number == 2) return true;
    if ((number&1) == 0) return false; // even numbers are not primes, except 2
    
    for (int i = 3; i <= number / 2; i+=2) // check only odd numbers
        if (number % i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

next step is to fix largest prime search:

```
BSTNode* largestPrime(BSTNode* root)
{
    if (root != nullptr) {
        BSTNode* maxPrime = isPrime(root->data) ? root : nullptr;
        
        BSTNode* maxLeftPrime = largestPrime(root->left);
        if (maxLeftPrime != nullptr && (maxPrime == nullptr || maxLeftPrime->data > maxPrime->data)) 
            maxPrime = maxLeftPrime;

        BSTNode* maxRightPrime = largestPrime(root->right);
        if (maxRightPrime != nullptr && (maxPrime == nullptr || maxRightPrime->data > maxPrime->data)) 
            maxPrime = maxRightPrime;

        return maxPrime;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

if you have actual binary search tree, where `max(left->data) <= node->data <= max(right->data)` then you can optimize function a little bit:

```
BSTNode* largestPrime(BSTNode* root)
{
    if (root != nullptr) {
        BSTNode* maxRightPrime = largestPrime(root->right);
        if (maxRightPrime != nullptr) return maxRightPrime;

        if (isPrime(root->data)) return root;
        
        BSTNode* maxLeftPrime = largestPrime(root->left);
        if (maxLeftPrime != nullptr) return maxLeftPrime;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk 3 will return true, because it will not enter into loop `(i <= number/2)`

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the BST property: since an in-order traversal will visit its values in sorted order, you could do an inverse in-order traversal, and at the *first* prime you find you can exit the recursion and return it all the way to the initial caller. Because of the BST order, you know this will be the greatest prime in the tree.

```
BSTNode* largestPrime(BSTNode* root)
{
    BSTNode* max = nullptr;
    if (root != nullptr) {
        BSTNode* temp = largestPrime(root->right);
        if (temp != nullptr) // Found it in subtree, get out of here.
            return temp;
        if (isPrime(root->data))
            return root; // Found it
        return largestPrime(root->left); // Not found yet, try left
    }
    return nullptr; // No prime found
}
```